# Why does the same executable use different RUNPATHs for different library lookups?

Tags: linux, shared-libraries

I have a Linux C++ program that builds & links (with `-Wl,--no-undefined`, no less) but fails to load all of its libraries when I try to run it.  I've been trying to inspect its dependencies with `ldd`, but I can't figure out why it's tripping over the library that's failing:

```
$ ldd standalone_test
   ...  lots of libraries that are found ...
libPythia6.so => not found
```

Now, this library *is* in a place where it ought to be found according to the `RUNPATH` embedded in the executable:

```
$ readelf -d ./standalone_test | grep "RUNPATH"
 0x000000000000001d (RUNPATH)            Library runpath: [/home/jeremy/code/NOvARwgt/cmake-build-debug/src:/home/jeremy/code/genie-2.12.2/lib:/opt/genie/GENIESupport/pythia6/v6_424/lib:/opt/root/lib:/cvmfs/nova-development.opensciencegrid.org/novasoft/releases/development/lib/Linux2.6-GCC-debug]
$ ls /opt/genie/GENIESupport/pythia6/v6_424/lib
liblund.a  libPythia6.so  pydata.o
```

(and both the executable  `standalone_test` and the library `libPythia6.so` are ELF64, so I don't think it's a processor architecture mismatch or something like that.)

I've tried digging further into what's going on during library loading, and I've noticed that different `RUNPATH`s are reported for the loading of different libraries under the same executable (some of these are 'chain' loads where they're requested by a library that was requested by the executable):

```
$ LD_DEBUG=libs,files ./standalone_test 2>&1 | ack RUNPATH
  # this one is the 'correct' RUNPATH (the one from the executable)
 19553:  search path=/opt/root/lib/tls/haswell/x86_64:/opt/root/lib/tls/haswell:/opt/root/lib/tls/x86_64:/opt/root/lib/tls:/opt/root/lib/haswell/x86_64:/opt/root/lib/haswell:/opt/root/lib/x86_64:/opt/root/lib        (RUNPATH from file ./standalone_test)
 # next one has been 'augmented' with processor architecture subdirs
 19553:  search path=/home/jeremy/code/NOvARwgt/cmake-build-debug/src/tls/haswell/x86_64:/home/jeremy/code/NOvARwgt/cmake-build-debug/src/tls/haswell:/home/jeremy/code/NOvARwgt/cmake-build-debug/src/tls/x86_64:/home/jeremy/code/NOvARwgt/cmake-build-debug/src/tls:/home/jeremy/code/NOvARwgt/cmake-build-debug/src/haswell/x86_64:/home/jeremy/code/NOvARwgt/cmake-build-debug/src/haswell:/home/jeremy/code/NOvARwgt/cmake-build-debug/src/x86_64:/home/jeremy/code/NOvARwgt/cmake-build-debug/src:/home/jeremy/code/genie-2.12.2/lib/tls/haswell/x86_64:/home/jeremy/code/genie-2.12.2/lib/tls/haswell:/home/jeremy/code/genie-2.12.2/lib/tls/x86_64:/home/jeremy/code/genie-2.12.2/lib/tls:/home/jeremy/code/genie-2.12.2/lib/haswell/x86_64:/home/jeremy/code/genie-2.12.2/lib/haswell:/home/jeremy/code/genie-2.12.2/lib/x86_64:/home/jeremy/code/genie-2.12.2/lib:/opt/genie/GENIESupport/pythia6/v6_424/lib/tls/haswell/x86_64:/opt/genie/GENIESupport/pythia6/v6_424/lib/tls/haswell:/opt/genie/GENIESupport/pythia6/v6_424/lib/tls/x86_64:/opt/genie/GENIESupport/pythia6/v6_424/lib/tls:/opt/genie/GENIESupport/pythia6/v6_424/lib/haswell/x86_64:/opt/genie/GENIESupport/pythia6/v6_424/lib/haswell:/opt/genie/GENIESupport/pythia6/v6_424/lib/x86_64:/opt/genie/GENIESupport/pythia6/v6_424/lib:/opt/root/lib:/cvmfs/nova-development.opensciencegrid.org/novasoft/releases/development/lib/Linux2.6-GCC-debug/tls/haswell/x86_64:/cvmfs/nova-development.opensciencegrid.org/novasoft/releases/development/lib/Linux2.6-GCC-debug/tls/haswell:/cvmfs/nova-development.opensciencegrid.org/novasoft/releases/development/lib/Linux2.6-GCC-debug/tls/x86_64:/cvmfs/nova-development.opensciencegrid.org/novasoft/releases/development/lib/Linux2.6-GCC-debug/tls:/cvmfs/nova-development.opensciencegrid.org/novasoft/releases/development/lib/Linux2.6-GCC-debug/haswell/x86_64:/cvmfs/nova-development.opensciencegrid.org/novasoft/releases/development/lib/Linux2.6-GCC-debug/haswell:/cvmfs/nova-development.opensciencegrid.org/novasoft/releases/development/lib/Linux2.6-GCC-debug/x86_64:/cvmfs/nova-development.opensciencegrid.org/novasoft/releases/development/lib/Linux2.6-GCC-debug      (RUNPATH from file ./standalone_test)
    ... more variants of these two ...
 # this one contains only a single entry from the real runpath??
 19553:  search path=/opt/root/lib      (RUNPATH from file ./standalone_test)
```

In the last case, the one where the library isn't located and the executable fails with a `cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` error, it moves on to looking in the system search path as well.

My question is: **how are these variants on `RUNPATH` concocted?**  I gather that they're modified by the various libraries that are requesting them somehow, but I can't seem to find any explanations out there on the googlewebs.  (Maybe I'm searching for the wrong thing?)  It seems like if I understood what was going on here, I'd be able to work backwards to understanding why the library isn't being found in the first place.

Comment: I believe `-Wl,--enable-new-dtags` should also be used to avoid some unusual path problems when `LD_PRELOADs` are used. It causes `DT_RUNPATH` rather than `DT_RPATH` dynamic header to be set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My question is: how are these variants on RUNPATH concocted?

Unlike older `RPATH`, the `RUNPATH` applies *only* when searching for *direct* dependencies of the binary.

That is, if `a.out` has `RUNPATH` of `/foo`, and `NEEDED` of `libfoo.so` (located in `/foo`), then `libfoo.so` will be found. But if `libfoo.so` itself depends on `libbar.so` (also located in `/foo`), and if `libfoo.so` does *not* have `RUNPATH`, then `libbar.so` will *not* be found.

This behavior promotes "every ELF binary should be self-sufficient". In the case above, `libfoo.so` is not self-sufficient (needs `libbar.so` but doesn't say where to find it).

If you use `RPATH` instead, the path there would apply to *every* search, and `libbar.so` will be found. You can achieve this with `-Wl,--disable-new-dtags` when linking `a.out`.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you!  Unfortunately I am dealing with some not-very-well-behaved (i.e. 'not self-sufficient' in your language) external libraries so I may be stuck with going for RUNPATH, or just relying on `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` (ugh).

Comment: ... and by `RUNPATH`, I mean `RPATH`.  sigh.

Comment: I don't think this answer explains where the different runpaths are coming from. If someone knows and can explain, that would be great.

Comment: @Andrew The question wasn't asking about that. In fact, the question itself _shows_ where the different `RUNPATH`s are coming from. If you have a question, just _ask_ (instead of commenting) -- it's free.

Comment: The question was exactly "how are these variants on RUNPATH" concocted." If you know, I'd love to hear the answer.

Comment: @Andrew "The question was exactly ..." and the answer explains _exactly_ that. You appear to have a question that is un-answered, but for some reason are refusing to ask it (at least not in words I can understand). Commenting further here is unlikely to be productive.